# Eclipse "aptana plugin" vs. jsdt (JavaScript Development Tools); where can I find a comparison chart?

Tags: javascript, php, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-kepler

I have just started using 'Eclipse Kepler' IDE for PHP programming and I'm now looking to use the same IDE for JavaScript, but I'm not sure which plugin to install?

I'm new to JavaScript so I'm not sure what is good to have; when I look at the Aptana and the JSDT plugin descriptions separately I'm not sure what the difference is and what I should be looking for. Can someone please help me. I have spent a few hours searching for a comparison but I find nothing on this topic; it feels like they are not even competitors (?).

I know I want auto-completion and debugging for HTML, CSS JavaScript and PHP (I think my php auto-completion and debugging is already good enough since I have PDT and Xdebug), but I'm not sure what else will make me more productive. If you have some other plugin for 'Eclipse Kepler' which I should be using for web application programming with JavaScript together with PHP please advice me.

Ps. I downloaded Aptana 3 as a seperate IDE but I have decided to go for Eclipse Kepler since it seemed to give me more functions and more freedom to expand my IDE (this might not be true but I especially missed the 'ctrl + hover + click' function in eclipse that takes me to object's and method's files which Aptana doesn't seem to have).

Best Regards 
Kriss

Answer (score 0):

I just recommend to use Aptana plugin as a tool for Web resources. 
As I know , Aptana is based on JSDT but has developed much more things than JSDT . 
You could just add Aptana plugin with your Kepler IDE like belows.

> Please copy the following Update Site URL to your clipboard and then follow the steps listed below to add this URL to your Available Software Sites list. Attempting to access this URL using your web browser will return an Access Denied error.
>   http://download.aptana.com/studio3/plugin/install

For your reference , JSDT project seems not to be very active for now.